# Completar registros en un nuevo campo en base a una consulta en SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente logica

```
Select Pac, OA, idComponente, Componente,
Hosp = case when idcomponente=1 then 1 else 0 end from Consumo_Hospitalario
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se requiere es que en el campo Hosp si la OA contiene componente "HAB CHICA" que su idcomponente es 1 sea 1 todas las relaciones que tenga esa OA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no se como lo haria en un query.

Comment: No sé entiende tu pregunta, tomate unos minutos y lee [ask]

Comment: que motor de BD utilizas?

Comment: ya madifique la pregunta

Comment: ¿cuantos valores de `idcomponente` puede haber? Si solo fueran los que muestras, bien podrías hacer `case when idcomponente in (1,5,7) then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: aya lo que sucede es que tengo varios componentes por una oa, osea puede que una oa tenga tres componente como el caso el ejemplo o pueda que tenga 10, y lo que se requiere es que si por la OA contiene por linea el componente=1 entonces todos los componentes se vuelven 1 ya que la oa contiene ese componente pero si la oa no contiene el componente 1 se vuelve cero, se entiende?

Comment: Creo que en ese caso deberia de declarar una variable y verificar que si tiene el componente HAB CHICA y el idcomponente 1 entonces le pones a la variable 1 y solo lo asiganas en tu select

Comment: Pero se volveria un procedure y ya no solamente una consulta, lo que sucede que no tengo acceso a procedure.

Comment: Hola te escribo una posible solucion y me indicas si te funciona y ahora vemos como resolverlo en caso de que no funcione esa

Answer (score 0):

Hola te anexe una posible solución como entendi tu problema algo asi necesitarias, si no es lo que buscas ahora vemos saludos

```
--CREO UNA TABLA VARIABLE SOLO PARA EFECTOS DE PRUEBA
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
PAC INT,
OA INT,
idComponente INT,
Componente VARCHAR(50)
)

--SIMULANDO DATOS
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (12345,25006215,1,'HAB CHICA'),(12345,25006215,5,'COLES...'),(12345,25006215,7,'MEDICINAS')
--NUEVOS
,(154789,25006266,15,'CAMA'),(154789,25006266,1,'HAB CHICA')
--NUEVOS PARA QUE DE 0
,(15478967,250062667,16,'CAMA 2'),(15478967,250062667,2,' NO HAB CHICA')

-- MI CTE
;WITH CTE AS (
Select Pac
from @Table Tbl
WHERE Componente='HAB CHICA' AND idComponente=1
)
Select tbl.Pac, OA, idComponente, Componente,
Hosp = case when Tbl.PAC=C.PAC then 1 else 0 end
from @Table Tbl
LEFT JOIN CTE C ON C.PAC= Tbl.PAC

--ASI QUEDARIA EL TUYO
;WITH CTE AS (
Select Pac
from Consumo_Hospitalario Tbl
WHERE Componente='HAB CHICA' AND idComponente=1
)
Select tbl.Pac, OA, idComponente, Componente,
Hosp = case when Tbl.PAC=C.PAC then 1 else 0 end
from Consumo_Hospitalario Tbl
LEFT JOIN CTE C ON C.PAC= Tbl.PAC
```

Comment: @EdgarVasquez me podrias dar un resumen de lo que me estas mostrando en el query, para entenderlo mejor

Comment: Claro en donde dice ASI QUEDARIA EL TUYO es un CTE para obetner los pac donde coincida tu condicion en ese obtenemos los datos posteriormente se realiza un select con un LEFT JOIN hacia el CTE para hacer un macth con las pac que coincidan y esas que coinciden son las que hay que ponerle 1 por eso en el case when se evalua Tbl.PAC=C.PAC

Comment: pero solo daria 1 a los que solamente tiene el código "Hab Chica" con el codigo del paciente y los demas 0, mas bien seria una manera de relacionar si el paciente tiene como componente "HAB CHICA" que todo sea 1 con ese paciente sino tienen en sus componentes "HAB CHICA" se vuelve cero todos sus componentes